# add space top of wordpress page after include functions.php

Tags: wordpress, function, space

after paste functions.php in wordpress theme , add space top of page !
even clear content functions.php but space top

functions.php :

or empty

but delete this file, space remove from page

help please !

include functions :

[image]

without functions :

[image]

functions content :

[image]

another screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Please copy the code from functions.php. It is impossible to help you otherwise.

Comment: code in functions.php is : <?php ?>

Comment: @Mohammad please make your post little more readable..explain it more about the problem

Comment: please recheck the question

Comment: @Mohammad can you add another screenshoot to display where is the space in your theme?

Comment: added another screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had something similar with Django template system, and it was due to encoding, consider to change your encoding of files from `UTF-8` to `UTF-8 without BOM`.